# Выполнение скрипта в пошаговом режиме в PyCharm - работает по-разному в схожих ситуациях

Tags: python, pycharm

Не могу понять, почему при выполнении учебного примера (код ниже) в пошаговом режиме в PyCharm с точкой останова на каждой строке (Shift+F9 для старта, затем F8 - каждый шаг) я вижу, как идёт заход в `__iter__` класса `myRange`, а вот как заходит в `__iter__` класса `MyGeneratorRange`, я не вижу - выглядит, как будто в `main` остаётся выполнение.

Тем не менее, если в `__iter__` этого класса поместить отладочный print, то видно, что он заходит каждый раз, как должен это сделать. И результаты верные. Скорее всего, я чего-то не знаю в PyCharm, но непонятно, что именно. Просьба подсказать, что это может быть - классы-то похожи.

Код из учебника Чернышова (убраны ненужные строки, код на несколько примеров рассчитан): https://github.com/MADTeacher/python_basics/blob/master/part5/operations_overloading_3_1.py.

```
class MyRange:
    def __init__(self, start, stop, step=1):
        self.start = start
        self.stop = stop
        self.step = step
        self.count_value = 0

    # Сюда вижу, как заходит
    def __iter__(self):
        self.count_value = self.start - self.step
        return self
  
    def __next__(self):
        if self.count_value+self.step >= self.stop:
            raise StopIteration
        self.count_value += self.step
        return self.count_value

class MyGeneratorRange:
    def __init__(self, start, stop, step=1):
        self.start = start
        self.stop = stop
        self.step = step

    # А сюда не вижу, как заходит
    def __iter__(self):
        count_value = self.start - self.step
        while count_value+self.step < self.stop:
            count_value += self.step
            yield count_value

if __name__ == "__main__":

    test_range = MyRange(0, 3)
    for firtst_it in test_range:
        print(f'firtst_it = {firtst_it}')
        for second_it in test_range:
            print(f'second_it = {second_it}, '
                    f'firtst_it*second_it = {firtst_it*second_it}')

    test_range = MyGeneratorRange(0, 3)
    for firtst_it in test_range:
        print(f'firtst_it = {firtst_it}')
        for second_it in test_range:
            print(f'second_it = {second_it}, '
                    f'firtst_it*second_it = {firtst_it*second_it}')
```

Comment: Клавишу 'F7' пробывал?

Comment: В первом варианте в `__iter__` заходит один раз - в начале итерации, а все последующие значения возвращаются с помощью вызова метода `__next__`. Во втором случае каждое следующее значение возвращается из `__iter__` с помощью `yield`. Технически, в первом случае сам объект является итератором (`__iter__` возвращает сам объект), а во втором - `__iter__` создает отдельный объект-итератор.

Comment: В обоих случаях в `__iter__` заходит, вы можете в этом убедиться, поставив точку останова внутри этого метода.

Comment: сергей вы не уточнили где точку останова ставили

Comment: P.S. ну и кстати да, только что проверил, при пошаговом выполнении через F7 ("с заходом" в функции) видно как везде заходит.

Comment: если поставить брекпоинт ниже if __name__ == "__main__": то по F8 не куда заходить не будет

Comment: @СергейШашко, да, спасибо, с F7 видно, как заходит! Но не понимаю разницу между этими двумя случаями - почему в случае, если это отдельный объект-итератор, то захода в него нет. Понимание итераторов пока слабое. И я уточнил сразу, где точку останова ставил - добросовестно делал "с точкой останова на каждой строке ".

Comment: @insolor, спасибо за пояснение, но не понимаю разницу между этими двумя случаями - почему в случае, если это отдельный объект-итератор, то захода в него нет по F8. И я знал, что на самом деле заходит - путём " поместить отладочный print"

Comment: F8 вообще "не входит" в функции (молча выполняет), если вы внутри функции не поставили точку останова. Если вы внутри методов не поставите точки останова, через F8 ни в первом, ни во втором случае вход в метод и не покажет. Скорее всего просто в первом `__init__` точку останова поставили, а во втором - нет.

Comment: @insolor, это ясно. Но я делал "с точкой останова на каждой строке ", как и написал в вопросе.  И F8 заходит только в ~__iter__~ класса ~myRange~, а F7 - в оба. (Не могу нормально iter выделить - тильдами же надо?)

Comment: Что "с точкой останова на каждой строке "? F8 не останавливается в каждой строке. `Не могу нормально iter выделить - тильдами же надо?` - обратным апострофом (на той же кнопки что тильда, только с shift)

Comment: @insolor, я на каждую строчку кода поставил красную точку справа (между номером и строкой). Я её называю "точкой останова" (неверно?). А потом нажал Shift+F9 один раз, а затем раз за разом нажимал F8. И в ~myRange~ он на каждой строке останавливался, заходя и в ~iter~

Comment: Значит во второй итер не поставили точку останова) У меня там останавливается, если точка останова стоит.

Comment: @insolor, поставил. Значит, с настройками что-то. Но, OK, не так важно, буду F7 пользовать. И искать обратный апостроф у меня на клавиатуре:-) Спасибо! (`нашел` - без Shift у меня)

Comment: правой клавичей мыши по установленому брейкпоинту можно условия задавать останова. Так на всякий случай вдруг кому-то в капилку

Comment: @СергейШашко, спасибо большое за совет. И у меня в списке дел записано "изучить детальнее PyCharm". Но там ещё и масса другого, типа "изучить Pandas", "обновить знания о сетях", "о системной архитектуре", "прочитать Буча" и т.д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итого, для работы в данном описанном случае требовалось для пошагового режима у меня нажимать F7, хоть точка останова и была в нужном месте установлена, и F8 должна была работать. При этом у других работает одинаково и с F8. Предположительно причина в каких-то настройках PyCharm.
Вывод:

1. Использовать F7, если F8 не обеспечивает требуемого.
2. Проверять настройки.